# Lower_bound gives other result

Tags: c++, lower-bound

testing lower_bound function in c++
Im getting weird result after running this code in Ideone.
What am I doing wrong? is auto usage correct here?

code :

```
    vector<int> a(5);
    a.clear();
    rep(i,0,5){
        a[i]=i+1;
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
        }
    cout<<endl;
    auto pos = lower_bound(a.begin(),a.end(),3);
    cout<< (pos-a.begin())<<'\n';
```

output :

```
1 2 3 4 5 
0
```

Why?? expected output :

```
2
```

What am I doing wrong I don't understand. seems like basic C++ code

Comment: Please get rid of all the useless typdefs and defines before posting on SO. It makes code 1000000 times more difficult to read.

Comment: Don't use macros for everything, it makes your code completely unreadable

Comment: Another post with those awful macros.  Where is this being taught?

Comment: And don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>` in the first place ...

Comment: It's good that you posted your full code, but that's not minimal (sooo many useless macros) and not reproducible (`bits/stdc++.h` is no header of the standard library, so thankfully, not every compiler supports it).

Comment: if your question is about the call to `lower_bound` then we do not need to see all the other stuff. You can hardcode the contents of the vector and a minimal example could be 3 lines of code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: Ok. I understand. I should post the needed code only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line creates a vector of five elements:

```
vector<int> a(5);
```

Next line removes all the five elements, setting the size to zero:

```
a.clear();
```

Consequently the loop writes beyond the `end()` of the vector, triggering undefined behavior. *This does not expand the vector.*

In practice you call `lower_bound` on an empty sequence, so `pos == a.begin()`. Remove the call to `clear()` in order to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh! Till today I thought a.clear() meant to set all the values inside the vector to 0. My god. Thank you so much. Now I understand.

Comment: @Akhil: `vector` constructor already initializes them to zero AND you are initializing them in the loop anyway. You don't need to initialize them a third time :)

Comment: Yes, I got it! @ybungalobill

Answer (score 4):

Your code has *undefined behavior*.

You are creating a `std::vector` with 5 `int`s in it, **and then you `clear()` the vector**, which sets its size back to 0.

Then you run a loop that accesses vector elements which are out of bounds of the vector's size. At this point, your code has *undefined behavior*. Anything could happen. Your code could crash. Your code could corrupt memory.

Then you call `std::lower_bound()` on an *empty* vector, so it returns the `end` iterator, which is the same as the `begin` iterator, so the distance between them is 0, which is what you print out.

You need to simply get rid of the call to `clear()`, then your code will work as you expect.